# How to get specific Times New Roman characters in Mojave

Tags: mojave

If I enter the unicode number for a specific character which is supposedly part of Times New Roman (ex: u+2190) I get the character but not in Times New Roman.  Is there any way to compel this?

Comment: Can you show how the character is supposed to look? I am entering that unicode but I don't seem to understand what you mean? Please see my example: https://imgur.com/a/kf8v61v

Comment: What app are you talking about?  Compelling display with a particular font will depend on the app.

Answer (score 1):

U+2190 is Leftwards Arrow.  On my machine the TNR version looks like this:

[image]

To have it look like this you will of course have to set the font for that character in your app to TNR.  Whether and how you can do that will depend on the app.

Comment: I eventually figured it out. Your answer helped. Thanks.